# Hidden Script found in a CakePHP site

Tags: php, cakephp, hidden, malware

I have a website using a CakePHP framework and somehow Trend Micro detected a malware in this website, what it does is it puts an iframe at the top of one of the files, problem is I can't find those iframe/code. I did experience this kind of malware where hackers inject a code in the index.php file but this one is really different. Here's screenshot from what Trend Micro found:

[image]

If you take a look, there's the source site called adimgsn07.co.in/k and if you open that site it says something like "bad country" on my end.

Does anyone encountered this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: From where did you get that code, the CakePHP application? Ask the developers about it.

Comment: like i'd said, Trend Mico found that malware and gave me that code. We're not sure if it is from CakePHP security flaw or something but I did ask about it as well.

Comment: Form security. Make sure they are handled correctly... especially the post

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a programming question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had something similar to this where a hacker had put a hidden link to a porn site inside an iframe on one of my websites.  The code was not easily spotted and the effect was it caused my website to crash so it simply displayed a blank, white page.

The hacker had managed to do this as I'd uploaded some changes using FTP instead of secure FTP so make sure you are using that and not insecure normal FTP.

The iframe is hosted at that URL shown but it looks like they have a typo in it but I am not going to visit it to check!

Comment: +1 for "I am not going to visit it to check" ;-)